# Optimal way to check all fields in a json data?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, data-structures

```
data = {u'name': None, u'region': None, u'id': u'test1', u'code': None,
        u'city': None, u'first_name': None, u'state_or_province': None,
        u'primary_phone': None, u'data2': [{u'status': u'deleted', u'name':
        u'b1', u'id': u'b1', u'modified_at': u'2016-07-13T10:22:47Z', u'eid':
        u'0012340', u'device_type': u'Mad box', u'custom_data': None,
        u'is_managed': True, u'number': None, u'sms_id': u'sms1'}],
        u'secondary_phone': None, u'sms_id': u'sms1', u'status': u'deleted',
        u'users': [{u'allow_content': False, u'status': u'deleted',
        u'sign_in_count': 0, u'max1': {u'TV': u'TV-MA', u'MPAA': u'NC-17',
        u'Unrated': u'UR'}, u'name': u'', u'subscriber_id': u'b1', u'gender':
        None, u'ids': [], u'modified_at': u'2016-07-27T10:18:19Z',
        u'allow_adult_content': False, u'sharing_threshold': {}, u'custom_data':
        None, u'user_id': u'test@test.com', u'email': None, u'sms_id': u'sms1'},
        {u'allow_unrated_content': None, u'status': u'deleted', u'sign_in_count':
        0, u'max_rating': {}, u'name': None, u'subscriber_id': u'testsub1',
        u'gender': None, u'offer_uri_ids': [], u'modified_at':
        u'2016-07-13T10:13:32Z', u'allow_adult_content': None,
        u'sharing_threshold': {}, u'custom_data': None, u'user_id': u'test',
        u'email': u'asdf@god.com', u'sms_id': u'sms1'}], u'ref':
        u'test@test.com', u'pin_code': None, u'credit_limit': 100.0,
        u'expiration': None, u'country': None, u'modified_at':
        u'2016-07-27T10:18:19Z', u'last_change_date': None, u'custom_data': None,
        u'address_line_1': None, u'address_line_2': None, u'change_id': None,
        u'billing_codes': []}
```

I need to verify all key's and value's for empty data.
Tried `if/else`s, but this takes too much code. Looking for better method than
the following:

```
parsed_json = [data]

if 'name' not in parsed_json[0]:
   print "name is not present"
if parsed_json[0]['name'] is "":
  print "name value is empty"
if 'region' not in parsed_json[0]:
  print "region is not present"
if parsed_json[0]['region'] is ""
  print "region value is empty"
```

Comment: Have you got an example of the code you've tried?

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: if 'name' not in  parsed_json[0]:
     print "name is not present"
if parsed_json[0]['name'] is "":
    print "name  value is empty"
if 'region' not in  parsed_json[0]:
     print "region is not present"

Comment: Need to verify each key and value to see if there is any empty data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a JSON object is a recursive data-structure, probably the easiest way to to do what you want is recursively:

```
def verify(key, value):
    if not value:
        print('"{}" is not present'.format(key))
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        for k, v in value.items():
            verify(k, v)
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        for i, element in enumerate(value):
            verify('{}[{}]'.format(key, i), element)

parsed_json = [data]

verify('parsed_json', parsed_json[0])
```

Note: This will consider numerical values like `0` and `0.0` as not present. If that's not what you want, you'll need to check for those types and modify the first `if` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3.x Code:**

```
for key, value in parsed_json[0].items():
  if value == "":
    print(key + " value is empty.")
```

Note: This code does not differentiate error messages by key (each one gets the same error message) and has not been properly escaped. If you're getting this data from untrusted sources (pro tip, they're all untrusted sources), you should have error catching/handling to account for missing/mangled key names.

Comment: Another easy test in that loop: `if key not in valid_keys: print(key + ' is not valid')`

Answer (score 1):

To get a filtered dictionary containing only empty values, you could do this:

**Python 2.x**

empty_values = {k:v for k,v in data.iteritems() if not v}

**Python 3.x**

empty_values = {k:v for k,v in data.items() if not v}